# Import errors (Image does not exist) external images (10000+ products)

Tags: magento-1.9, import

I am doing a CSV import for 10.000 + products with external URL's for the images.

The strange thing is that 4000 products get imported perfect (products with AND without images) but 6000+ products don't get imported and the error for every skipped product: "Image does not exist.".

Kinda strange since it doesn't matter if there is an image or not (at least this works for the 4000 products the do get imported.

Any idea's what could be the problem?

UPDATE:

After a couple of tries now 6092 of 10000+ get imported and its exactly the same CSV file. Hope somebody can enlighten me..

Comment: Perhaps the host of the URLs is throttling access? A lot of sites throttle bootleg web crawlers like that. You might try spoofing the user agent that your importer is using and see if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Magento doesn't like importing files that are too large.  You may be better off separating them into different files. Do 2000 at a time?

To upload images you need to create a separate ***Dataflow Profile.
System > Import/Export > Dataflow – Profiles***

Name it Image upload (or whatever you like) and map the sku & image fields.  Also image labels if you want to do so.

Save the new profile.

The import image csv now need to be in a separate spreadsheet with only the columns that you have mapped (must have sku & images).  For the images column include JUST the file name.  No slash required.  I.e image01.jpg

If product needs multiple images just duplicate the row with the same sku & put in the next images name.

FTP & go to your media folder and create new folder called import.  Upload your images in there (make sure files have the same name!)

And upload like you did the products.
Make sure under data format that Original Magento attributes in first row is set to No.

Comment: The external images are working great for the 6000 products that do get imported, the import just skips 4000 row and give the error "Image does not exist.".

For now i will try and do 5 x 2000 at a time and will let you know if that solves the problem. I just thought it was some other issue since the first couple of clean imports it imported around 4000, and now it imports 6000 of the total 10000+.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose your product sku is - `sku1`, and your product image is `sku1.jpg`

You must place `sku1.jpg` inside `media\import` folder

and your csv file will look likes:

`sku,image
sku1,/sku1.jpg`

I successfully imported my products.